# javascript return array of nested object and arrange similar types

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

javascript return array of nested object and arrange similar types

I have objects

```
let obj1 = { categoryId:1, category:"Fruits", name:"Orange"}
let obj2 = { categoryId:1, category:"Fruits",name:"Apple"}
let obj3 = { categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Onion"} 
let obj4 = { categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Ginger"}....etc
```

I want to create a array of nested object from this array expected:

```
let result =   

 [
         {
          name: "Fruits", values: [
            {
            "categoryId": 1,
            "category": "Fruits",
            "name": "Orange"
            }, 
            {
            "categoryId": 1,
            "category": "Fruits",
            "name": "Apple"
          }
         ]
        },
         { name:"Vegetables", values: [
            {
            "categoryId": 2,
            "category": "Vegetables",
            "name": "Onion"
            }, 
            {
            "categoryId": 2,
            "category": "Vegetables",
            "name": "Ginger"
          }
         ]
        }
    ]
```

I am looking for a function to add to the map one by one not all at once

```
addtoArray( obj1);
addtoArray( obj2); 
addtoArray( obj3); 
addtoArray( obj4);....etc
```

Also a remove function:

```
removeFromArray( obj1);
```

In delete the object must not be same:

```
{ categoryId:1, category:"Fruits", name:"Orange", newItem:"newvalue"}
```

It should be deleted using `category:"Fruits"` reference

Deleting an object, until no more objects are in the group. Then the group gets removed as well.

What I tried is below

```
function addtoArray(collection, object) {
    if (!collection[object.category]) {
        collection[object.category] = [object];
        return;
    }
    if (collection[object.category].includes(object)) return;
    collection[object.category].push(object);
}

function removeFromArray(collection, object) {
    if (!collection[object.category]) return;
    var index = collection[object.category].indexOf(object);
    if (index === -1) return;
    collection[object.category].splice(index, 1);
    if (!collection[object.category].length) delete 
    collection[object.category];
}

var obj1 = { categoryId: 1, category: "Fruits", name:"Orange" },
    obj2 = { categoryId: 1, category: "Fruits", name:"Apple" },
    obj3 = { categoryId: 2, category: "Vegetables", name:"Onion" },
    obj4 = { categoryId: 2, category: "Vegetables", name:"Ginger" },
    collection = {};
```

Please guide me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function for adding to the array:

```
var arr=[];

const addToArray=(arr,obj)=>{
  const index=findByName(arr,obj.category);
  if(index>-1){
    arr[i].values.push(obj)
  }else{
    arr.push({
      name:obj.category,
      values:[obj]
    })
  }
}
const findByName=(arr,name)=>{
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].name===name)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

addToArray(arr,obj1)
```

Comment: Thanks bro it helps

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing various lookups on your data, array is not the recommended way to go.
You'll need to traverse it each time you'd like to take out an object.
Instead, use a class with some helpers.

The first step is adding unique ids to your data:

```
let obj1 = { id: 0, categoryId:1, category:"Fruits", name:"Orange"}
let obj2 = { id: 1, categoryId:1, category:"Fruits",name:"Apple"}
let obj3 = { id: 2, categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Onion"} 
let obj4 = { id: 3, categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Ginger"}
```

The second part is create a class to hold this data and allow you to manipulate it:

```
class MyCollection {
  constructor() {
    this.items = {};
  }

  addItem(item) {
    this.items[item.id] = item;
  }

  removeItem(item) {
    delete this.items[item.id]
  }

  removeGroup(group) {
    for(key in this.items) {
      if(this.collection[key] === group) {
        delete this.collection[key];
      }
    }
  }

  toArray() {
    return Object.values(this.items);
  }

}
```

usage:

```
const collection = new MyCollection();
collection.add(obj1);
collection.add(obj2);
collection.add(obj3);
collection.removeGroup("Fruits");
collection.items; // {2: { id: 2, categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Onion"} }

//or should you desire to return an array
collection.toArray(); // [{ id: 2, categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Onion"}]
```

Comment: Buddy I need to return as array of object. I mean all you done inside an object how I can do it?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a `.toArray()` method which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Does the structure HAVE to be like the one you showed above? In my opinion, a following structure would be much cleaner:

```js
const result = {
  Fruits: [ {categoryId: 1, category: "Fruits", name: "orange"}, ... ],
  Vegetables: [ ... ]
}
```

With this structure, your code would look like this:

```
let obj1 = { categoryId:1, category:"Fruits", name:"Orange"}
let obj2 = { categoryId:1, category:"Fruits",name:"Apple"}
let obj3 = { categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Onion"} 
let obj4 = { categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Ginger"}

const objs = [ obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 ]

const addToCollection = (collection, obj) => {
    if (!collection[obj.category]) {
        collection[obj.category] = []
    }
    collection[obj.category].push(obj)
}

const removeFromCollection = (collection, obj) => {
    if (!collection[obj.category]) return

    collection[obj.category] = collection[obj.category].filter((o) => {
        return o.name !== obj.name
    })
}


const result = {}

objs.forEach((obj) => {
    addToCollection(result, obj)
})

console.log(result)

removeFromCollection(result, obj2)

console.log(result)
```

Which is also quite efficient, because the correct category can be found quickly.

Output:

```
{
  Fruits: [
    { categoryId: 1, category: 'Fruits', name: 'Orange' },
    { categoryId: 1, category: 'Fruits', name: 'Apple' }
  ],
  Vegetables: [
    { categoryId: 2, category: 'Vegetables', name: 'Onion' },
    { categoryId: 2, category: 'Vegetables', name: 'Ginger' }
  ]
}


{
  Fruits: [
    { categoryId: 1, category: 'Fruits', name: 'Orange' }
  ],
  Vegetables: [
    { categoryId: 2, category: 'Vegetables', name: 'Onion' },
    { categoryId: 2, category: 'Vegetables', name: 'Ginger' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ni I am looking for that structure